# Print_r only show first row

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have the following code :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT result FROM table1");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
print_r($result);
```

What I want to do here is only to check whether the data that selected above will be displayed or not, but the result from `print_r` only show the first row of the data. 
for example the result : `Array ( [0] => 2 [result] => 2 )` 
When i check on the database, there's nothing wrong with the data. After the first row, there are still other rows.
Maybe it's kinda stupid question, but can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) only fetches one row. You'll need to iterate over multiple rows by using a loop. See the [examples at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#example-1802). Note that `mysql_*` functions are depreciated. I suggest using PDO or MySQLi, instead. Incidentally, PDO allows you to fetch all rows at once with [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a while to fetch all rows and not only the first one:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT result FROM table1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    print_r($row); 
}
```

For every call of `mysql_fetch_array` it fetch only one row and when there are no more row is then you get false back.

The while loop and call for every loop `mysql_fetch_array` so long until they get false back.

You can also write to get 2 rows, but then you have "static" code and nor more then 2 rows:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT result FROM table1");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

and if you have only one row in the table you get this results:

```
$row1 = Array ( [0] => 2, [result] => 2 );
$row2 = false;
```

Comment: @aureliadsp it is working because you are looping to every row using ‛while‛ loop

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask for it but **Do NOT** use `mysql_*` as it has been removed, you can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead like this.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","your_user_name","your_password","your_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT result FROM table1";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Fetch all rows as an associative array
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print '<pre>';    
print_r($rows);
print '</pre>';    

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following, you will get everything in one shot:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Works from v5.3.0+. Sources: [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp)

Note that you would need to have MySQLnd as your native driver!

> Available only with [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php).

To print it in a more structured way, here is how:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT result FROM table1");
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($count>0){
 //anything here
}
```